# How to set 2 different camera view perspective for reference image at same time?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, image, image-sequence

How do I set "1 camera" view for the front image and "2 cameras" for the side images? "2 cam" refuse to change the view instead, it changes the same  view perspective from "1 cam"

here is the picture:

[image][image]

Please don't forget to demonstrate pictures, gifs, or upload blends files. to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Try toggling with Ctrl-Alt-Q for a 4-window view. You can then change each window individually.